# Copying files from SFTP to S3 using Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig, sftp

I have a large number of files of very large size (in GB) that need to be copied efficiently from a remote SFTP server to an AWS S3 bucket. I was considering using a Pig script running in a AWS Elastic MapReduce (EMR) cluster for the purpose however have been enable to find specific information on how to create the script to perform the task. Is this achievable using a Pig script and if yes is there an example that I can follow?

Comment: Can you provide any more details? For example, how many files, average file size, how often? That will impact the recommended strategy.

Comment: There are a few hundred files on the server between 1-3 GB. The files are generated each day and need to be copied over to an S3 bucket that comprises the input of another EMR job flow.

Comment: Why on earth would `Pig` be your initial choice to accomplish this task?